# Check Answer in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, compare, nsmutablearray

When i run this code and press the "next" button. i get a bad excess error. What i want it to do is to check if what the user enters compares with the index of a given Label which changes every time the user enters the correct answer.
For example: naam.text =@"Natriumfluoride". Then formule.text has to have the same index in "formules" as in "namen".

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender {

    if ([formule.text isEqualToString:[formules objectAtIndex:x]]) {
        x = arc4random() % x;
        naam.text = [namen objectAtIndex:x];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    formules = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"NaNO3",@"NaCH3COO",@"NaCl",@"NaBr",@"NaI",@"Na2SO4",@"NaF",@"Na2S",@"NaOH",@"Na2SO3",@"Na2CO3",@"Na3PO4",@"Na2O",nil];

    namen = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Natriumnitraat",@"Natriumacetaat",@"Natriumchloride",@"Natriumbromide",@"Natriumjodide",@"Natriumsulfaat",@"Natriumfluoride",@"Natriumsulfide",@"Natriumhydroxide",@"Natriumsulfiet",@"NatriumCarbonaat",@"Natriumfosfaat",@"Natriumoxide", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    x = arc4random() % [formules count];
    naam.text = [namen objectAtIndex:x];
}
```

Anyone knows what my problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to retain your arrays after creation

```
[formules retain];
[namen retain];
```

if you are using arc use [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
or define your arrays as strong property

Comment: Well, that was a simple solution! I was wondering if you could tell me why i had to do so? What is the function of retaining them?

Comment: because your array will be released and doesnt exists after viewDidLoad. on next:sender you try to access it and you app crashes.with retain you say that you need an object longer.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for explaining and solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with a point that why have you written `x = arc4random() % x;`maybe you could have written like `x = arc4random() % 10;` .Also you are checking from random values.You should put a for loop that should check every value of the array with your label.

Comment: You're right but i already changed it to x = arc4random() % [formules count]; That was a little mistake. But wasn't the main problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok but why are you using random values?Can you explain the logic behind that?

Comment: That's because i don't want The text to show on a specific order. I want to show it randomly. It's an application for learning some chimistry stuff. So if it keeps repeating the words in the same order, it's not very usefull for learning. And this is a very good way of randomizing the words I think.